# CASE with IN clause

Tags: sql, obiee

I have a condition (in Business objects ) as below

```
=If([Actual ]=0;Sum([Applied] In ([Project];[ Name];[Number];[Sub ])))
```

which I need to convert it to CASE statement for my OBIEE

Below is the query I had tried but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
    WHEN F.ACTUAL_EQP_COST = 0 
        THEN SUM((F.HRS_APPLIED) IN(F.PROJECT,F.NAME,F.NUMBER,F.SUB)) 
    ELSE 0 
    END 
FROM  F
```

Comment: Try editing your question with sample data and desired results.  The query makes no sense.

Comment: What does this "Sum([Applied] In ([Project];[ Name];[Number];[Sub ])" mean?

Comment: I believe those inside IN () are column names .... seems like they are flags or something like that

Comment: Translate the BO statement to English first.  Then you'll have an easily understood requirement for your sql.

Comment: "it doesn't work" <-- did you get an error ? Did it run but you got the wrong answer?

Answer (score 1):

Probably

```
select SUM(F.HRS_APPLIED) 
from DTS_OSC_WIP_REP_CST_ANALYSIS_A F
where F.ACTUAL_EQP_COST = 0 
group by F.PROJECT,F.WIP_ENTITY_NAME,F.OPERATION_NUMBER,F.OPERATION_SUB_SEQ
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "in" inside a "then" statement.
I couldn't understand exactly but something in this direction might help:

```
select 
CASE WHEN F.ACTUAL_EQP_COST = 0 
THEN (SELECT SUM(F1.HRS_APPLIED) 
FROM DTS_OSC_WIP_REP_CST_ANALYSIS_A F1 
WHERE F1.column_name IN (F.PROJECT,F.WIP_ENTITY_NAME,F.OPERATION_NUMBER,F.OPERATION_SUB_SEQ)) 
ELSE 0 END 
from DTS_OSC_WIP_REP_CST_ANALYSIS_A F
```